# ¿Por que la imagen de mi header no se muestra completamente?

Tags: html, css

quisiera saber por que la imagen del header no se muestra completamente, ya eh intentado de todo, la estoy haciendo responsive, a veces se pone, a veces no... y ya no se que hacer.

Este es el código:
'''

```css
header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;

    background-image: url(./imgs/header_t.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
} 
.container
{
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
                <div class="container container-text">
                    <a href="#" class="text" target="_blank"><b><em>FELICIDADES!!!</em></b></a>
                </div>
        </header>
```

'''
esta es la imagen que puse
[image: Esta es la imagen]

Y así es como se ve [image: una imagen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema puede estar en tu imagen, que no está ocupando el tamaño máximo del contenedor, prueba con estas propiedades:

```
header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    background-image: url(./imgs/header_t.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4000;


    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

O también, el problema puede ser tu clase `container` que ocupa el 85% (o por el max-width), por eso la imagen se recorta hasta ese tamaño, pruébalo así:

```
.container
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo!!!

Comment: A usted, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar este problema:

hay que verificar bien la ruta de la imagen local, que en tu caso es **../imgs/** desde el archivo CSS.

La URL debe ser entre comillas simples o dobles dentro del paréntesis:

```
background-image: url(" ");
```

Y este es el ejemplo:

```css
header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;

    background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/700/400/nature");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
} 
.container
{
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
                <div class="container container-text">
                    <a href="#" class="text" target="_blank"><b><em>FELICIDADES!!!</em></b></a>
                </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta con el ✓ si te a servido. Cualquier otra consulta, realiza otra pregunta nueva